# Extending angular2 component decorator

Tags: angular

With angular 2.0.0-beta.8 I've created a couple of custom decorator that extends the @Component decorator.

To make that I've used this code:

```
import {..., View } from 'angular2/core';

...

export var MyCustomComponent:ComponentFactory =
    <ComponentFactory>makeDecorator(MyCustomComponentMetadata, (fn:any) => fn.View = View);
```

Now, with angular 2.0.0-beta.12, the 'View' decorator has been dropped so the import throw an error because 'angular2/core' has no exported member 'View'.

How I'm supposed to create a custom component decorator?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking for. `@Component()` + `@View()` have become just `@Component()` Can't you just extend `@Component()` instead of `@View()`?

Comment: To make `MyCustomComponent` decorator, I need to call the function `makeDecorator` that, as second argument, takes `(fn:any) => fn.View = View`. For this to compile, I need to import `View`.
I don't want to extend the `@View()` decorator but only the `@Component()` decorator.

Comment: Can't you use `Component` instead, view ceased to exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {MyCustomComponentMetadata} from ...;

export function MyCustomComponent(config: MyCustomComponentMetadata) {
  return function(cls) {
    var annotations = Reflect.getMetadata('annotations', cls) || [];
    annotations.push(new Component(config));
    Reflect.defineMetadata('annotations', annotations, cls);
    return cls;
  };
};
```

Comment: I've slightly modified this code to fit my requirements and seems to work great! One question, why I need to do `const _reflect: any = Reflect;`? Can I just use `Reflect`?

Comment: Angular 6 no more uses Reflecttion for metadata. To know how to override the built-in Component decorator please check here http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2018/7/extending_component_decorator_angular_6

Answer (score 1):

Angular 6 no more uses Reflection to define metadata for components. To override the built-in component decorator you could do something like below,

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import componentRegistry from './ComponentRegistry';
 
function MyComponent(args: any = {}): (cls: any) => any {
  const ngCompDecorator = Component(args);
 
  return function (compType: any) {
    ngCompDecorator(compType);
    args.type && componentRegistry.register(args.type, compType, args.model);
  }
}
 
export default MyComponent;
```

They metadata is stored in a static property called `__annotations__` in the component's constructor. To know more about this please check [here](http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2018/7/extending_component_decorator_angular_6)

Comment: I have (probably) an idea what is the code doing but I would really appreciate to roughly ducment each line :) thanks

Comment: I have found it:) http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2018/7/extending_component_decorator_angular_6