# Extending Component decorator angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-decorator

I know this question has been posted many times, but not for angular 7. It seems they changed something because doing it like it is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51256389/1056512 is not working anymore.
Here's the code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export function CustomElement(args: any = {}): (cls: any) => any {
  const ngCompDecorator = Component(args);

  return function(compType: any) {
    ngCompDecorator(compType);
  };
}
```

The Decorator use

```
@CustomElement({
  selector: 'multiple',
  templateUrl: './multiple.html',
  styleUrls: ['./multiple.scss']
})
```

I have the following error: `Failed to load multiple.html`

What's happening here?

EDIT:
My package dependencies:

> ```
> "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
> "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
> "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
> "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
> "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
> "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
> "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
> "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
> "core-js": "^2.5.4",
> "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
> "tslib": "^1.9.0",
> "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
> ```

Stackblitz is running on 7.0.1 and mine is on 7.2.0

Comment: I have the same problem, were you able to arrive to a solution?

Comment: Unfortunatly, no :( I had to give up this solution because it was really time consuming